# Access class members in Property Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a document class Which has several properties and depending on the document type I want to export data in excel or pdf.

The simplified version of my Document class looks like this:

```
public class Document
{
     public int ID { get; set;}

     public string SaleInfo { get; set; }

     public string PurchaseInfo { get; set; }

     public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; } 
}
```

The DocumentType enum looks like this:

```
public enum DocumentType : Byte
{
    PurchaseDocument = 1,
    SaleDocument
}
```

I have created Exportable attribute which looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class Exportable : Attribute
{
    public bool ExportableInExcel = true;
    public bool ExportableInPdf = true;
}
```

The problem I have is that this code doesn't works (I can't access class members in attribute):

```
public class Document
{
     public int ID { get; set;}

     //this keyword isn't accessible
     [Exportable(ExportableInExcel = (this.DocumentType == DocumentType.SaleDocument))]
     public string SaleInfo { get; set; }

     public string PurchaseInfo { get; set; }

     public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; } 
}
```

So, I am interested in, is there any possibility to change or add something on attribute level to solve this problem?

Comment: No, you can't use attributes like that. What you should be using is a property in the class like `ExportableToExcel` that examines that property. This isn't the right use-case for attributes.

Comment: It will make my class more complicated, But it seems I have to do so..

Comment: If you really wanted to use the attribute here, you can, but you should make a method on the attribute that takes the `Document` class and returns true/false or the enum value based on the `SaleInfo` property value, but that seems like a lot of work to avoid an `if` statement in your code.

Comment: Why would you not use reflection to decide what to export?

Comment: I have created One method which depending on this attribute exports specific properties in excel or pdf and I use reflection in it. but this class is different in it that when document type is SaleDocument, I have to export SaleInfo and for PurchaseDocument - PurchaseInfo. To do so, I have to put additional logic in it. And if I have one other class which will have another property like 'DocumentType', I have to do the same.